# Phase on Aharonov-Bohm effect doubts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance, berry-pancharatnam-phase

How I show that $$\Lambda(\textbf{x}')=\frac{q}{\hbar}\int \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{x'}$$ on $$
\tilde{\psi}(\textbf{x}',t)=e^{[\frac{iq\Lambda(\textbf{x}')}{\hbar c}]}\psi(\textbf{x}',t)$$ for [Aharonov-Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect)? I don't know about path integral formulation, that was suggested on Sakurai,J.J. book... There is other way to show that? Using the gauge transform for $$\tilde{\mathbf{A}}=\mathbf{A}+\nabla\mathbf{\Lambda}~ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to show by direct substitution that your proposed wave function $\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{x},t)$ solves the Schroedinger equation, where the vector potential is included via the [minimal coupling prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_coupling)
$$ \mathbf{p} \to \mathbf{p} - \mathrm{i} q \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})$$
(up to a sign convention for $\mathbf{A}$ and some dimensionful constants which I may have got wrong), so long as $\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ is the solution when $\mathbf{A} = 0$.